# Channel Videos - Removing Video When Saving

Tags: ee3, devdemon, channel-videos

I have used DevDemon's channel videos on numerous occasions and always found it very useful. I have just installed the plugin on a EE 3.5.7 install, searched and browsed for the required video and all looks as expected. However, hit save and the video os removed and quotes "No Videos have been added."

Has anyone else came across this or is it a bug? Really hoping that this is a simple fix as the end user loves the feature and is keen to get it working for the site.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you
Scott

Comment: I also have this issue? Will let you know if I discover anything.

Comment: Great thanks. Are you using EE3.5.9?

Comment: Same thing here. Every new video has "invalid date" and isn't saved.

Comment: Gave up in the end and removed the plugin, shame but didnt get a response.

Comment: Same issue here. Have tried updating with no luck. Anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: @ScottHarrington and others -- see my answer here: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/40390/376

Answer (score 0):

(I'm with DevDemon)

A cause of this issue we've seen in the past is a user's cache folder not being writeable. Make sure your cache folder is writeable and it should fix this problem.